# How do I edit this to fit what is required?

Tags: java

I am writing this program for my class. It requires my return to be

```
[0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.0]
```

However, I only manage to get to

```
0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.0]
```

Is there any way to change anything inside the `nestedCircle` to fulfill the requirement?

- the `nestedCircle` must contain a recursion
- can only change everything below `nestedCircle`
- can x, y are just part of the given question so it could be ignored

```java
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String []args) {
        System.out.println(nestedCircle(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.05, ""));
    }

    public static String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double radius, double diff, String radiusList) {
        // your code goes here. Task 1.
        radius = (double) Math.floor(radius * 100) / 100;
        if (radius <= 0) {
            return "0.0]";
        } else {
            radiusList = radius + ", " + nestedCircle(x, y, radius-diff, diff, radiusList);
        }
        return radiusList;
    }
}
```

Comment: So you're asking about the leading `[` that is missing, right? Just add `if (radiusList.isEmpty()) { radiusList = "["; }`

Comment: What is the purpose of `String result = "";`?

Comment: *FYI:* `Math.floor(double)` returns a `double`, so that cast is unnecessarily redundant.

Comment: What does `x` and `y` have to do with anything?

Comment: x and y have nothing to do with, it is just part of the question. string result could be removed. math,.floor is one of the other requirement cuz it requires us to cut things like 0.36 to 0.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can only modify what's inside, some alternatives  in order to check if you need to append `[` at the beginning of your string:

**1.** **`System.Properties`**

**2.** **`Env Variables`**

**3.** **Do stupid things** - *(recommended)*

**4.** **Mom, I may be dumb**

---

**`-1-`** **`System.Properties`**

```
String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double r, double d, String radiusList) 
{
   boolean start=false;
   if (System.getProperty("startnested")==null)
   {
      System.setProperty("startnested","true");
      start=true;
   }         
   r = (double) Math.floor(r * 100) / 100;
   if (r <= 0) 
      return "0.0]";
   radiusList = (start ? "[" : "") +r+ ", " +nestedCircle(x, y, r-d, d, radiusList);
   
   return radiusList;
}
```

---

**`-2-`** **`Reflection and envs`**

```
String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double r, double d, String radiusList) 
{
   boolean start = false;
   Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
   Field field = env.getClass().getDeclaredField("m");
   field.setAccessible(true);
   if (((Map<String, String>) field.get(env)).get("nested") == null)
   {
      (((Map<String, String>) field.get(env)).put("nested","true"); 
       start=true;
   }    
           
   r = (double) Math.floor(r * 100) / 100;
   if (r <= 0) 
     return "0.0]";
   radiusList = (start ? "[" : "") + r + ", " +nestedCircle(x, y, r-d, d, radiusList);
   
   return radiusList;
}
```

---

**`-3-`**  **`Just implement the weirdest idea you could think of`**

*This is strongly recommended.*

```
String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double r, double d, String radiusList) 
{
   boolean start=false;
   try 
   {
     System.in.available();
     start=true;
     new Scanner(System.in).close();
   } catch (IOException e) {}
   
   r = (double) Math.floor(r * 100) / 100;
   if (r <= 0) 
      return "0.0]";
   radiusList = (start ? "[" : "") +r+", "+nestedCircle(x, y, r-d, d, radiusList);
   
   return radiusList;
}
```

*Code maintainers will love this snippet so much. They just love these things a lot. It's a disgrace to software engineering, but who cares anyway.*

---

**`-4-`** **`Mom, am I dumb?`**

*The answer to the question is "probably, son".*

Add the initial bracket unconditionally and replace it (**`.replace("[" , "")`**) for each result of the recursive calls. The root invocation won't be affected, leaving the initial `[` properly. And that's it.

```
String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double r, double d, String radiusList) 
{ 
   r = (double) Math.floor(r * 100) / 100;
   if (r <= 0) 
      return "0.0]";
   
   return "[" + r + ", "+ nestedCircle(x,y,r-d,d,radiusList).replace("[" , "");
}
```

**`.substring(1)`** would probably be more appropiate, but then the last return `"0.0]"` should include a dummy prefix, such as a blank space or a character.

```
String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double r, double d, String radiusList) 
{  
   r = (double) Math.floor(r * 100) / 100;
   if (r <= 0) 
       return "@0.0]";
 
   return "[" + r + ", "+ nestedCircle(x,y,r-d,d,radiusList).substring(1);    
}
```

:_ )

---

**`-5-`** **`Yes, son`**

---

### Conclusions

**1**. *Approach nº 3 is recommended*

Comment: Quite a contortion, but a great idea if you have only the code inside the method to work with.  It's basically a way of making a global variable out of nothing.  Just realize that you can only do this once if you can't put code anywhere else to reset the property.\

Comment: @hauki it's a troll approach, but, actually, ...it will do it. (*99% of the time, unless System.in was previously closed*). The first time, `System.in.avaliable()` will return correctly, `start` will be set to true and then....we close `System.in` *"forever"*. In the next iteration, `avaliable()` will throw an exception. *So stupid but so lovely*

Comment: Great answer! So many options...and finally the recommended approach...there are so many good things in this answer for learners.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is to reuse the `radiusList` parameter.  The parameter currently serves no purpose.  It is the empty string for every call to the method.  By reusing it, you can signal the first call of the method really easily:

```
class HelloWorld{

    public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(nestedCircle(0.5, 0.5, 0.4, 0.05, ""));
    }
    public static String nestedCircle (double x, double y, double radius, double diff, String radiusList) {
        // your code goes here. Task 1.
        radius = (double) Math.floor(radius * 100) / 100;
        String result = "";
        if (radius <= 0) {
            return "0.0]";
        } else {
            radiusList = ((radiusList.length() == 0)? "[" : "") +  radius + ", " + nestedCircle(x, y, radius-diff, diff, "x");
        }

        return radiusList;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
[0.4, 0.35, 0.3, 0.25, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.0]
```

One nice thing about this is that the same call to the method will work multiple times without having to reset the System property or otherwise do some sort of reset between calls.

Comment: This is so clean and clever. Cheers.

Comment: I updated my answer to solve the problem by only modifying a single line inside the `nestedCircle` method.